# method call from adapter class to activity

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, static-methods

Adapter:

```
check_list_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        JPrequirements.prepareSelection(v, getAdapterPosition());
    }
});
```

`JPrequirements` is the activity. and `prepareSelection` is non-static method inside activity. I cannot access it from adapter.

ERROR:

> non static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Which is right. that's why I tried with:

```
JPrequirements().prepareSelection(v, getAdapterPosition()); // Creating an instance...
```

But, the problem is I lost all activity component here. eg. layout components and other supporting variables. I don't want that. What is the best way to deal with this? How can I get updated value from adapter to activity? So, I can display it real-time.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this via `interface`. Firstly, define an `interface` class as:

```
public interface ActivityAdapterInterface {
    public void prepareSelection(View v, int position);
}
```

Now, implement the `interface` in your `Activity` as:

```
public class JPrequirements extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityAdapterInterface {
    ...
    public void prepareSelection(View v, int position) {
        // cool stuff here
    }
    ...
}
```

Make sure you pass `this` interface reference to your `Adapter` via its constructor. Then finally call it on click as:

```
check_list_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mActivityAdapterInterface.prepareSelection(v, getAdapterPosition());
    } 
});
```

**[EDIT]**

To provide the `interface` to your `Adapter` provide it the constructor.

```
public class YourAdapter ... {

    private ActivityAdapterInterface mActivityAdapterInterface;

    public YourAdapter(..., ActivityAdapterInterface activityAdapterInterface) {
        activityAdapterInterface = mActivityAdapterInterface;
    }

}
```

Comment: exactly like this :-)

Comment: how do I get `mActivityAdapterInterface` in adapter?

Comment: @RonakPatel check my adapter above

Comment: How can I show progress in the interface by the interface?